# How to create nested files in welcome view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 folders with some views that I want to display on the welcome/main index of my rails app.

```
Views
 Main
  Owner
   info.html
```

I can route to the file but the controller for main has no direction on how to get there. I tried

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

 def owner
  def info
   end
end
```

But I know this isn't right. What do I need to do?

Comment: create a partial with the common HTML content, then render the partial on different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can handle this,

Using namespaces,

```
# app/controllers/owner/main_controller.rb
module Owner
  class MainController < ApplicationController
    def info
    end
  end
end

# app/views/owner/main/info.html
<html>...</html>
```

Note the change in file structure of view

or with explicit render with name of view

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def info
    render 'main/owner/info' # Relative path from app/views
  end
end
```